# Running into problem with benders decomposition from scip

Tags: c++, scip

I'm running into a strange error when solving a problem with SCIP. This does not happen for all instances, but for a few. I just wanted to ask if someone knows, what the error message means exactly and if I would need to turn off something specifically when solving the Problem with the Bender's Default from SCIP.

The exact error message is:

```
[scip_probing.c:259] ERROR: not in probing mode
[benders.c:4944] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:1503] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:4406] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:4243] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[scip_probing.c:259] ERROR: not in probing mode
[benders.c:4944] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:1503] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:4406] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:4243] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[scip_probing.c:259] ERROR: not in probing mode
[benders.c:4944] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:1503] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:4406] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:4243] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[benders.c:3805] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[scip_benders.c:630] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[cons_benders.c:555] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[cons.c:3765] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[sol.c:1742] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[primal.c:1593] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[solve.c:3016] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[solve.c:3887] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[solve.c:4187] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[solve.c:4983] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
[scip_solve.c:2678] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SCIPException'
  what():  method cannot be called at this time in solution process
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and occurs during the presolving process.

I'm using the ScipOptSuite 8.0 and implement my problem via C++.

Comment: Could you submit a bug report containing the instance file that you are trying to solve? You can either submit it through the bug report form https://scipopt.org/bugs.php or by opening an isssue on github: https://github.com/scipopt/scip/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the mistake myself. There were some problems with the parameters you can specify within SCIP. For Benders Decomposition you need to turn off the restarts in the solving process, but due to a mistake in the order of putting these parameters it was not turned off.